# Sitecore.Social: Social messages index could not be determined for master database

Tags: solr, indexing

We are on Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160519 (Update-3) and using SOLR 6.2.1

Logs on one of our CM server is suddenly overflowing with the following error message:

> Sitecore.Social: Social messages index could not be determined for
>   master database. Messages root path: /sitecore/social/Messages. Please
>   check indexes configuration.

This behavior is sudden, and does not seem to have been predicated by any code/content changes.  Performance on our CM/CD servers is suddenly at a crawl.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if you have this setting on config files? <FolderTemplateId>{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}</FolderTemplateId> it should be on excluded templates section on Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config; could you please try the following commenting out the FolderTemplateId

Comment: This configuration file is disabled in my Sitecore instance. Thus, this should not be the case.

Comment: can you search for this settings on other files?

Comment: i found  4 occurrences for this item id {A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523} in 'admin/showconfig.aspx'
one for each data base prefetch configuration (core, master, web)
and one in 'sitecore_suggested_test_index': in exclude list

Comment: can you comment on sitecore_suggested_test? is it on excludetemplate?

Comment: Yes. it is there in exclude folder section and not in excludetemplate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71816/discussion-between-arvind-gehlot-and-sitecore-climber).

Comment: Ever find a solution?